# How to execute a PL/SQL table statements

Tags: plsql

Dear friends i have these statements stored in a table and i need to execute them to receive the result.

```
DECODE (to_char((SELECT s1.streettypename FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||''|| to_char((SELECT s0.streetname FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||''|| to_char(NRO_VIA) ||''|| to_char(NRO_PUERTA),'', 'No Disponible', to_char((SELECT s1.streettypename FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||' '|| to_char((SELECT s0.streetname FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||' '|| to_char(NRO_VIA) ||' '|| to_char(NRO_PUERTA))',DECODE (to_char((SELECT s1.streettypename FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||''|| to_char((SELECT s0.streetname FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||''|| to_char(NRO_VIA) ||''|| to_char(NRO_PUERTA),'', 'No Disponible', to_char((SELECT s1.streettypename FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||' '|| to_char((SELECT s0.streetname FROM autodesk.smstreets s0, autodesk.smstreettypes s1 where s0.streettypeid = s1.streettypeid(+) AND s0.streetantiq=0 AND s0.streetid=COD_VIA)) ||' '|| to_char(NRO_VIA) ||' '|| to_char(NRO_PUERTA)) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

DECODE (observaciones, NULL, 'No Disponible', '', 'No Disponible', observaciones)',DECODE (observaciones, NULL, 'No Disponible', '', 'No Disponible', observaciones) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char((SELECT areaname FROM autodesk.amareas a0 WHERE a0.areaid=COD_DISTRITO))',to_char((SELECT areaname FROM autodesk.amareas a0 WHERE a0.areaid=COD_DISTRITO)) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char((SELECT areaname FROM autodesk.amareas a0 WHERE a0.areaid=COD_PROVINCIA))',to_char((SELECT areaname FROM autodesk.amareas a0 WHERE a0.areaid=COD_PROVINCIA)) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(correlativo)',to_char(correlativo) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

sed',sed FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(telefono)',to_char(telefono) FROM s_v_cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(numero_medidor)',to_char(numero_medidor) FROM tps.s_v_medid, cliente c WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(d.Consumo)',to_char(d.Consumo) FROM cliente c,(SELECT Id_Cuenta, Consumo FROM (SELECT a.Id_Cuenta, b.ENERGIA_FP Consumo FROM s_NUC_SERVICIO a, s_his_consumo b WHERE UPPER(a.tipo_Servicio) = 'ELECTRICO' AND a.id_servicio=b.id_servicio AND a.Id_Cuenta= %ID_ELEMENTO% ORDER BY fecha_lectura DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <=1) d WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(d.Potencia)',to_char(d.Potencia) FROM cliente c,(SELECT Id_Cuenta, Potencia FROM (SELECT a.Id_Cuenta, (SELECT potencia_cont_fp FROM s_v_cliente WHERE numero_cliente = a.Id_Cuenta) Potencia FROM s_NUC_SERVICIO a, s_his_consumo b WHERE UPPER(a.tipo_Servicio) = 'ELECTRICO' AND a.id_servicio = b.id_servicio AND a.Id_Cuenta = %ID_ELEMENTO% ORDER BY fecha_lectura DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <=1) d WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

fase',fase FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(NRO_CLIENTE)',to_char(NRO_CLIENTE) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

nombre',nombre FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(pcr)',to_char(pcr) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

TO_CHAR(DECODE(TIPO,1,'NORMAL',2,'MAXIMETRO',4,'PIMT',7,'HH.UU. Y PP.JJ',8,'ALUMBRADO PUBLICO','No Disponible'))',TO_CHAR(DECODE(TIPO,1,'NORMAL',2,'MAXIMETRO',4,'PIMT',7,'HH.UU. Y PP.JJ',8,'ALUMBRADO PUBLICO','No Disponible')) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

TO_CHAR(DECODE(estado,0,'ACTIVO',1,'ELIMINADO',2,'RETIRADO',3,'NUEVO',4,'PROCESO DE RETIRO','No Disponible'))',TO_CHAR(DECODE(estado,0,'ACTIVO',1,'ELIMINADO',2,'RETIRADO',3,'NUEVO',4,'PROCESO DE RETIRO','No Disponible')) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

cadena',cadena FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(sector)',to_char(sector) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'

to_char(zona)',to_char(zona) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @miMescua .  To get the best answers it will be helpful for you to edit you question to provide more information.  Specifically, your desired result, a sample of input data, and in what way is your current attempt not performing properly.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as it appears, these are all select statements that return 1 row of 2 columns (minus the keyword `select` at the start, and with syntax errors in many) then you could do this:

```
declare
  l_sql long;
  l_col1 long;
  l_col2 long;
begin
  for r_sql in (select statement from my_table) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Statement: '||r_sql.statement);
    l_sql := 'select '||r_sql.statement;
    begin
      execute immediate l_sql into l_col1, l_col2;
      dbms_output.put_line('returned: '||l_col1||','||l_col2);
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        -- take appropriate action
      when too_many_rows then ...
        -- take appropriate action
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

But that will only work when the syntax errors in the data have been fixed - e.g.

```
to_char(NRO_CLIENTE)',to_char(NRO_CLIENTE) FROM cliente WHERE NRO_CLIENTE='104631'
```

... has a spurious ' after `to_char(NRO_CLIENTE)` that will cause the statement to fail when run.